# SSIS package upgrade 2008 to 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, upgrade, ssis-2008, ssis-2017

I am very new to SSIS and I am upgrading SSIS package 2008 to 2017.
I have opened Visual Studio 2017 and create solution and add existing package into it.

After adding some warning is showing related to configuration file and script task so how to solve this warning.

> Warning at AMLPayeeExtract []: The configuration file name "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages\AMLPayeeExtract\amlconfig.dtsConfig" is not valid. Check the configuration file name.
>
> Warning at Generate GetATFSchema Script [Generate GetATFSchema Script]: Found SQL Server Integration Services 2008 Script Task "ST_0539b0a0794b4574b2a367f76fa2193e" that requires migration!

After adding existing package in SSDT package will migrate but how to recheck SSIS package after solution of warning.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services-packages-using-the-ssis-package-upgrade-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you Hadi for this link but my issue has not resolved.